# Data Web Controls

Tags: asp.net

In a repeater control can we achive both sorting and grouping together, If possiple plz guide me the way.

If not, what is the best control to obtain just sorting and grouping.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in data control with grouping and sorting which works out of the box in .net framework. You need to implement sorting and grouping by yourself. As implemented solutions you can look at [devexpress gridview](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GroupingSorting/Sorting.aspx) or [jquery grid plugin](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx).

If you want to implement sorting in repeater control - look at [this](http://www.asp.net/Learn/Data-Access/tutorial-45-vb.aspx).